# Raspberry Pi system crashes when running GUI

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I wrote a GUI using python tkinter, it runs normally in PC ( when I use ssh to control   Raspberry) but always cause system crash when running in Raspberry pi.

When I try to drag the GUI, the system stops to response. Even when I click on the title bar of the GUI, the system crashes.

This GUI contains following functions: control PWM duty cycle of 6 GPIOs, set on and off time, save and read setting through pickle file.

Is the problem caused by raspripi? Or is it caused by my inefficient program? Or is it caused by tkinter?

Any comment would be welcome, thanks a lot!

The code is something like this:

```
import time

__author__='duanyujia'

#!/usr/bin/python
#-*- coding: iso-8859-1 -*-

#need to import some libraries to let this code work
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename,asksaveasfilename
from tkinter.messagebox import showerror
from RPIO import PWM
import socket
import math
import pickle
import _thread

class LEDChooser(object):
def __init__(self):

    #initialize some vital variables
    self.start_button_state = 0
    self.r = 0
    self.hr = 0
    self.fr = 0
    self.b = 0
    self.w = 0
    self.t = 0
    self.f = 0
    self.start = 0
    self.stop = 0
    self.set = 0

    #initialize UI framework
    frame = Tk()
    self.frameThread = frame
    self.connection_status=StringVar()

    initialize PWM
    self.servo = PWM.Servo(0, 3000, 1)
    self.servo.set_servo(4, 2999)
    self.servo.set_servo(14,2999)
    self.servo.set_servo(15, 2999)
    self.servo.set_servo(17, 2999)
    self.servo.set_servo(18, 2999)
    self.servo.set_servo(7,2999)

    #title of the window
    frame.title("LED Contol Panel")


    ##main body of GUI
    Label(text="Current time:").grid(row=1,column=0)
    Label(text="Mode", relief=RIDGE, width=16).grid(row=7,column=0)
    Label(text="Red", relief=RIDGE, width=16).grid(row=7,column=1)
    Label(text="HyRed", relief=RIDGE, width=16).grid(row=7,column=2)
    Label(text="FrRed", relief=RIDGE, width=16).grid(row=7,column=3)
    Label(text="Blue", relief=RIDGE, width=16).grid(row=7,column=4)
    Label(text="White", relief=RIDGE, width=16).grid(row=7,column=5)
    Label(text="On", relief=RIDGE, width=20).grid(row=7,column=7,columnspan=5)
    Label(text="Off", relief=RIDGE, width=20).grid(row=7,column=13,columnspan=5)
    Label(text="Set Time", relief=RIDGE, width=20).grid(row=10,column=7,columnspan=5)

    #Timer
    Label(text=":",width=2).grid(row=8, column=8)
    Label(text=":",width=2).grid(row=8, column=10)
    Label(text=":",width=2).grid(row=8, column=14)
    Label(text=":",width=2).grid(row=8, column=16)
    Label(text=" ",width=2).grid(row=8, column=12)
    Label(text=" ",width=2).grid(row=8, column=6)

    self.start_time_h = StringVar()
    self.start_time_h.set("00")
    self.start_time_h_entry = Entry(frame, textvariable=self.start_time_h, width=4)
    self.start_time_h_entry.grid(row=8,column=7)

    self.start_time_m = StringVar()
    self.start_time_m.set("00")
    self.start_time_m_entry = Entry(frame, textvariable=self.start_time_m, width=4)
    self.start_time_m_entry.grid(row=8,column=9)

    self.start_time_s = StringVar()
    self.start_time_s.set("00")
    self.start_time_s_entry = Entry(frame, textvariable=self.start_time_s, width=4)
    self.start_time_s_entry.grid(row=8,column=11)

    self.stop_time_h = StringVar()
    self.stop_time_h.set("00")
    self.stop_time_h_entry = Entry(frame, textvariable=self.stop_time_h, width=4)
    self.stop_time_h_entry.grid(row=8,column=13)

    self.stop_time_m = StringVar()
    self.stop_time_m.set("00")
    self.stop_time_m_entry = Entry(frame, textvariable=self.stop_time_m, width=4)
    self.stop_time_m_entry.grid(row=8,column=15)

    self.stop_time_s = StringVar()
    self.stop_time_s.set("00")
    self.stop_time_s_entry = Entry(frame, textvariable=self.stop_time_s, width=4)
    self.stop_time_s_entry.grid(row=8,column=17)

    self.save_start_time_h = StringVar()
    self.save_start_time_h.set("")
    Label(textvariable=self.save_start_time_h).grid(row=11, column=7)
    self.save_start_time_m = StringVar()
    self.save_start_time_m.set("")
    Label(textvariable=self.save_start_time_m).grid(row=11, column=9)
    self.save_start_time_s = StringVar()
    self.save_start_time_s.set("")
    Label(textvariable=self.save_start_time_s).grid(row=11, column=11)
    self.save_stop_time_h = StringVar()
    self.save_stop_time_h.set("")
    Label(textvariable=self.save_stop_time_h).grid(row=11, column=13)
    self.save_stop_time_m = StringVar()
    self.save_stop_time_m.set("")
    Label(textvariable=self.save_stop_time_m).grid(row=11, column=15)
    self.save_stop_time_s = StringVar()
    self.save_stop_time_s.set("")
    Label(textvariable=self.save_stop_time_s).grid(row=11, column=17)

    #current time
    self.timeText = Label(frame, text="")
    self.timeText.grid(row=1, column=1)

    #self.connection_status=StringVar()
    self.update_timeText()

    #default modes
    self.light_mode = StringVar()
    self.light_mode.set(1)

    #start button and exit and save and read button
    self.start_button = Button(frame, text='startnow')
    self.start_button.grid(row=14, column=0)
    self.start_button.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>', self.start_now)

    self.save_button = Button(frame, text='save',relief = 'raised')
    self.save_button.grid(row=14, column=1)
    self.save_button.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>', self.save_setting)

    self.read_button = Button(frame, text='read')
    self.read_button.grid(row=14, column=2)
    self.read_button.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>', self.read_setting)

    exit_button = Button(frame, text='exit')
    exit_button.grid(row=14, column=3)
    exit_button.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>', exit)

    exit_button = Button(frame, text='set time')
    exit_button.grid(row=14, column=4)
    exit_button.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>', self.set_time)

    #Germination mode setting
    self.light_mode_switch1 = Radiobutton(frame, variable=self.light_mode,
                                          value=1, command=self.customEnable, text='Germination')                                                                                    
    self.light_mode_switch1.grid(row=8, column=0)

    self.value_r_g = StringVar()
    self.value_r_g.set("0")
    self.value_r_g_entry = Entry(frame, textvariable=self.value_r_g)
    self.value_r_g_entry.grid(row=8,column=1)

    self.value_hr_g = StringVar()
    self.value_hr_g.set("0")
    self.value_hr_g_entry = Entry(frame, textvariable=self.value_hr_g)
    self.value_hr_g_entry.grid(row=8,column=2)

    self.value_fr_g = StringVar()
    self.value_fr_g.set("0")
    self.value_fr_g_entry = Entry(frame, textvariable=self.value_fr_g)
    self.value_fr_g_entry.grid(row=8,column=3)

    self.value_b_g = StringVar()
    self.value_b_g.set("0")
    self.value_b_g_entry = Entry(frame, textvariable=self.value_b_g)
    self.value_b_g_entry.grid(row=8,column=4)

    self.value_w_g = StringVar()
    self.value_w_g.set("0")
    self.value_w_g_entry = Entry(frame, textvariable=self.value_w_g)
    self.value_w_g_entry.grid(row=8,column=5)

    #Seedling mode setting
    self.light_mode_switch2 = Radiobutton(frame, variable=self.light_mode,
                                          value=2, command=self.customEnable, text='Seedling')
    self.light_mode_switch2.grid(row=9, column=0)

    self.value_r_s = StringVar()
    self.value_r_s.set("0")
    self.value_r_s_entry = Entry(frame, textvariable=self.value_r_s)
    self.value_r_s_entry.grid(row=9,column=1)

    self.value_hr_s = StringVar()
    self.value_hr_s.set("0")
    self.value_hr_s_entry = Entry(frame, textvariable=self.value_hr_s)
    self.value_hr_s_entry.grid(row=9,column=2)

    self.value_fr_s = StringVar()
    self.value_fr_s.set("0")
    self.value_fr_s_entry = Entry(frame, textvariable=self.value_fr_s)
    self.value_fr_s_entry.grid(row=9,column=3)

    self.value_b_s = StringVar()
    self.value_b_s.set("0")
    self.value_b_s_entry = Entry(frame, textvariable=self.value_b_s)
    self.value_b_s_entry.grid(row=9,column=4)

    self.value_w_s = StringVar()
    self.value_w_s.set("0")
    self.value_w_s_entry = Entry(frame, textvariable=self.value_w_s)
    self.value_w_s_entry.grid(row=9,column=5)

    #Vegetative mode setting
    self.light_mode_switch3 = Radiobutton(frame, variable=self.light_mode,
                                          value=3, command=self.customEnable, text='Vegetative')
    self.light_mode_switch3.grid(row=10, column=0)

    self.value_r_v = StringVar()
    self.value_r_v.set("0")
    self.value_r_v_entry = Entry(frame, textvariable=self.value_r_v)
    self.value_r_v_entry.grid(row=10,column=1)

    self.value_hr_v = StringVar()
    self.value_hr_v.set("0")
    self.value_hr_v_entry = Entry(frame, textvariable=self.value_hr_v)
    self.value_hr_v_entry.grid(row=10,column=2)

    self.value_fr_v = StringVar()
    self.value_fr_v.set("0")
    self.value_fr_v_entry = Entry(frame, textvariable=self.value_fr_v)
    self.value_fr_v_entry.grid(row=10,column=3)

    self.value_b_v = StringVar()
    self.value_b_v.set("0")
    self.value_b_v_entry = Entry(frame, textvariable=self.value_b_v)
    self.value_b_v_entry.grid(row=10,column=4)

    self.value_w_v = StringVar()
    self.value_w_v.set("0")
    self.value_w_v_entry = Entry(frame, textvariable=self.value_w_v)
    self.value_w_v_entry.grid(row=10,column=5)

    #Flowering mode setting
    self.light_mode_switch4 = Radiobutton(frame, variable=self.light_mode,
                                          value=4, command=self.customEnable, text='Flowering')
    self.light_mode_switch4.grid(row=11, column=0)

    self.value_r_f = StringVar()
    self.value_r_f.set("0")
    self.value_r_f_entry = Entry(frame, textvariable=self.value_r_f)
    self.value_r_f_entry.grid(row=11,column=1)

    self.value_hr_f = StringVar()
    self.value_hr_f.set("0")
    self.value_hr_f_entry = Entry(frame, textvariable=self.value_hr_f)
    self.value_hr_f_entry.grid(row=11,column=2)

    self.value_fr_f = StringVar()
    self.value_fr_f.set("0")
    self.value_fr_f_entry = Entry(frame, textvariable=self.value_fr_f)
    self.value_fr_f_entry.grid(row=11,column=3)

    self.value_b_f = StringVar()
    self.value_b_f.set("0")
    self.value_b_f_entry = Entry(frame, textvariable=self.value_b_f)
    self.value_b_f_entry.grid(row=11,column=4)

    self.value_w_f = StringVar()
    self.value_w_f.set("0")
    self.value_w_f_entry = Entry(frame, textvariable=self.value_w_f)
    self.value_w_f_entry.grid(row=11,column=5)

    #Custom mode setting
    self.light_mode_switch5 = Radiobutton(frame, variable=self.light_mode,
                                          value=5, command=self.customEnable, text='Custom')
    self.light_mode_switch5.grid(row=12, column=0)

    self.value_r_c = StringVar()
    self.value_r_c.set("0")
    self.value_r_c_entry = Entry(frame, textvariable=self.value_r_c)
    self.value_r_c_entry.grid(row=12,column=1)

    self.value_hr_c = StringVar()
    self.value_hr_c.set("0")
    self.value_hr_c_entry = Entry(frame, textvariable=self.value_hr_c)
    self.value_hr_c_entry.grid(row=12,column=2)

    self.value_fr_c = StringVar()
    self.value_fr_c.set("0")
    self.value_fr_c_entry = Entry(frame, textvariable=self.value_fr_c)
    self.value_fr_c_entry.grid(row=12,column=3)

    self.value_b_c = StringVar()
    self.value_b_c.set("0")
    self.value_b_c_entry = Entry(frame, textvariable=self.value_b_c)
    self.value_b_c_entry.grid(row=12,column=4)

    self.value_w_c = StringVar()
    self.value_w_c.set("0")
    self.value_w_c_entry = Entry(frame, textvariable=self.value_w_c)
    self.value_w_c_entry.grid(row=12,column=5)

    #setting default size of the windows
    frame.geometry("1400x500+300+300")

    #start the UI
    frame.mainloop()

    #enable disable
def customEnable(self):
    if self.light_mode.get()=='1':
        self.light_mode_switch1.configure(state="normal")
        self.light_mode_switch1.update()
        self.r = int(self.value_r_g.get())
        self.value_r_g_entry.configure(state="normal")
        self.value_r_g_entry.update()
        self.value_hr_g_entry.configure(state="normal")
        self.value_hr_g_entry.update()
        self.value_fr_g_entry.configure(state="normal")
        self.value_fr_g_entry.update()
        self.value_b_g_entry.configure(state="normal")
        self.value_b_g_entry.update()
        self.value_w_g_entry.configure(state="normal")
        self.value_w_g_entry.update()

        self.light_mode_switch2.configure(state="normal")
        self.light_mode_switch2.update()
        self.value_r_s_entry.configure(state="disabled")
        self.value_r_s_entry.update()
        self.value_hr_s_entry.configure(state="disabled")
        self.value_hr_s_entry.update()
        self.value_fr_s_entry.configure(state="disabled")
        self.value_fr_s_entry.update()
        self.value_b_s_entry.configure(state="disabled")
        self.value_b_s_entry.update()
        self.value_w_s_entry.configure(state="disabled")
        self.value_w_s_entry.update()

        self.light_mode_switch3.configure(state="normal")
        self.light_mode_switch3.update()
        self.value_r_v_entry.configure(state="disabled")
        self.value_r_v_entry.update()
        self.value_hr_v_entry.configure(state="disabled")
        self.value_hr_v_entry.update()
        self.value_fr_v_entry.configure(state="disabled")
        self.value_fr_v_entry.update()
        self.value_b_v_entry.configure(state="disabled")
        self.value_b_v_entry.update()
        self.value_w_v_entry.configure(state="disabled")
        self.value_w_v_entry.update()

        self.light_mode_switch4.configure(state="normal")
        self.light_mode_switch4.update()
        self.value_r_f_entry.configure(state="disabled")
        self.value_r_f_entry.update()
        self.value_hr_f_entry.configure(state="disabled")
        self.value_hr_f_entry.update()
        self.value_fr_f_entry.configure(state="disabled")
        self.value_fr_f_entry.update()
        self.value_b_f_entry.configure(state="disabled")
        self.value_b_f_entry.update()
        self.value_w_f_entry.configure(state="disabled")
        self.value_w_f_entry.update()

        self.light_mode_switch5.configure(state="normal")
        self.light_mode_switch5.update()
        self.value_r_c_entry.configure(state="disabled")
        self.value_r_c_entry.update()
        self.value_hr_c_entry.configure(state="disabled")
        self.value_hr_c_entry.update()
        self.value_fr_c_entry.configure(state="disabled")
        self.value_fr_c_entry.update()
        self.value_b_c_entry.configure(state="disabled")
        self.value_b_c_entry.update()
        self.value_w_c_entry.configure(state="disabled")
        self.value_w_c_entry.update()

    if self.light_mode.get()=='2':
        self.light_mode_switch1.configure(state="normal")
        self.light_mode_switch1.update()
        self.value_r_g_entry.configure(state="disabled")
        self.value_r_g_entry.update()
        self.value_hr_g_entry.configure(state="disabled")
        self.value_hr_g_entry.update()
        self.value_fr_g_entry.configure(state="disabled")
        self.value_fr_g_entry.update()
        self.value_b_g_entry.configure(state="disabled")
        self.value_b_g_entry.update()
        self.value_w_g_entry.configure(state="disabled")
        self.value_w_g_entry.update()

        self.light_mode_switch3.configure(state="normal")
        self.light_mode_switch3.update()
        self.value_r_v_entry.configure(state="disabled")
        self.value_r_v_entry.update()
        self.value_hr_v_entry.configure(state="disabled")
        self.value_hr_v_entry.update()
        self.value_fr_v_entry.configure(state="disabled")
        self.value_fr_v_entry.update()
        self.value_b_v_entry.configure(state="disabled")
        self.value_b_v_entry.update()
        self.value_w_v_entry.configure(state="disabled")
        self.value_w_v_entry.update()

        self.light_mode_switch4.configure(state="normal")
        self.light_mode_switch4.update()
        self.value_r_f_entry.configure(state="disabled")
        self.value_r_f_entry.update()
        self.value_hr_f_entry.configure(state="disabled")
        self.value_hr_f_entry.update()
        self.value_fr_f_entry.configure(state="disabled")
        self.value_fr_f_entry.update()
        self.value_b_f_entry.configure(state="disabled")
        self.value_b_f_entry.update()
        self.value_w_f_entry.configure(state="disabled")
        self.value_w_f_entry.update()


def start_now(self,event):
    self.start_transmission()
    #transmission
def start_transmission(self):
    self.get_trans_value()
    print(self.light_mode.get())
    print(self.r)
    print(self.hr)
    print(self.fr)
    print(self.b)
    print(self.w)
    print(self.f)
    print("start PWM")
    red = math.trunc(2999 * ((self.r)/10.0))
    hred = math.trunc(2999 * ((self.hr)/10.0))
    fred = math.trunc(2999 * ((self.fr)/10.0))
    blue = math.trunc(2999 * ((self.b)/10.0))
    white = math.trunc(2999 * ((self.w)/10.0))
    self.fan = math.trunc(2999*((self.f)/10.0))

    self.servo.set_servo(4, red)
    self.servo.set_servo(14, blue)
    self.servo.set_servo(15, hred)
    self.servo.set_servo(17, white)
    self.servo.set_servo(18, fred)
    print( "r hr fr b w f", red, hred, fred, blue, white,self.fan)
    self.start_button_state=1
    self.loop = 1
    if self.set == 1:
        self.printtime_stop()
    if self.set == 0:
        pass

    #get transfer value
def get_trans_value(self):
    if self.light_mode.get()=='1':
        self.r = int(self.value_r_g.get())
        self.hr = int(self.value_hr_g.get())
        self.fr = int(self.value_fr_g.get())
        self.b = int(self.value_b_g.get())
        self.w = int(self.value_w_g.get())
    if self.light_mode.get()=='2':
        self.r = int(self.value_r_s.get())
        self.hr = int(self.value_hr_s.get())
        self.fr = int(self.value_fr_s.get())
        self.b = int(self.value_b_s.get())
        self.w = int(self.value_w_s.get())
    if self.light_mode.get()=='3':
        self.r = int(self.value_r_v.get())
        self.hr = int(self.value_hr_v.get())
        self.fr = int(self.value_fr_v.get())
        self.b = int(self.value_b_v.get())
        self.w = int(self.value_w_v.get())
    if self.light_mode.get()=='4':
        self.r = int(self.value_r_f.get())
        self.hr = int(self.value_hr_f.get())
        self.fr = int(self.value_fr_f.get())
        self.b = int(self.value_b_f.get())
        self.w = int(self.value_w_f.get())
    if self.light_mode.get()=='5':
        self.r = int(self.value_r_c.get())
        self.hr = int(self.value_hr_c.get())
        self.fr = int(self.value_fr_c.get())
        self.b = int(self.value_b_c.get())
        self.w = int(self.value_w_c.get())
    self.f = 10

    #update current time
def update_timeText(self):
    self.current = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
    # Update the timeText Label box with the current time
    self.timeText.configure(text = self.current)
    self.frameThread.after(1000, self.update_timeText)

    #compare time functions
def compare_start(self, event):
    self.printtime_start()
def compare_start_again(self):
    self.printtime_start()

def refresh_time_value(self):

    self.save_start_time_h.set(self.start_time_h.get())
    self.save_start_time_m.set(self.start_time_m.get())
    self.save_start_time_s.set(self.start_time_s.get())
    self.save_stop_time_h.set(self.stop_time_h.get())
    self.save_stop_time_m.set(self.stop_time_m.get())
    self.save_stop_time_s.set(self.stop_time_s.get())

    Label(text=":",width=2).grid(row=11, column=8)
    Label(text=":",width=2).grid(row=11, column=10)
    Label(text=":",width=2).grid(row=11, column=14)
    Label(text=":",width=2).grid(row=11, column=16)
    Label(text=" ",width=2).grid(row=11, column=12)
    Label(text=" ",width=2).grid(row=11, column=6)




def printtime_start(self):
    if self.start == 1:
        self.printstart()
    else:
        self.update_timeText()
        self.timestring = str(self.current)  
        if self.timestring[0]== self.save_start_time_h.get()[0] and self.timestring[1] == self.save_start_time_h.get()[1]:
            if self.timestring[3]== self.save_start_time_m.get()[0] and self.timestring[4] == self.save_start_time_m.get()[1]:
                if self.timestring[6]== self.save_start_time_s.get()[0] and self.timestring[7] == self.save_start_time_s.get()[1]:
                    self.start =1
                    print(self.timestring)
        self.frameThread.after(1000, self.printtime_start)

def printtime_stop(self):        
    if self.stop == 1:
        self.transmit_stop()
    else:
        self.time_cycle()
        self.loop += 1
        self.update_timeText()
        self.timestring = str(self.current)
        if self.timestring[0]== self.save_stop_time_h.get()[0] and self.timestring[1] == self.save_stop_time_h.get()[1]:
            if self.timestring[3]== self.save_stop_time_m.get()[0] and self.timestring[4] == self.save_stop_time_m.get()[1]:
                if self.timestring[6]== self.save_stop_time_s.get()[0] and self.timestring[7] == self.save_stop_time_s.get()[1]:
                    self.stop =1
                    print(self.timestring)
        self.frameThread.after(1000, self.printtime_stop)

#fan control function        
def time_cycle(self):
    if self.loop == 1:
       self.servo.set_servo(7, self.fan) 
    if self.loop < 11:
        pass
    if self.loop == 11:
        self.servo.set_servo(7, 0)
    if self.loop > 11 and self.loop < 61:
        pass
    if self.loop == 61:
        self.loop = 0

def printstart(self):
    self.start=0
    print("start")
    self.start_transmission()

#modify this when come back
def set_time(self,event):
    self.refresh_time_value()
    if self.start_button_state == 1:
        if self.set == 0:
            self.printtime_stop()
            self.set=1
        if self.set == 1:
            pass
    if self.start_button_state == 0:
        self.compare_start_again()
        self.set=1

def transmit_stop(self):
    self.stop = 0
    print("stop")
    self.servo.set_servo(4, 0)
    self.servo.set_servo(14, 0)
    self.servo.set_servo(15, 0)
    self.servo.set_servo(17, 0)
    self.servo.set_servo(18, 0)
    self.servo.set_servo(7, 0)
    print("done")
    self.start_button_state = 0
    self.compare_start_again()

def save_setting(self,event):
    self.settings = [int(self.value_r_g.get()),int(self.value_hr_g.get()),
                        int(self.value_fr_g.get()),int(self.value_b_g.get()),
                        int(self.value_w_g.get()),#germination
                        int(self.value_r_s.get()),int(self.value_hr_s.get()),
                        int(self.value_fr_s.get()),int(self.value_b_s.get()),
                        int(self.value_w_s.get()),#seedling
                        int(self.value_r_v.get()),int(self.value_hr_v.get()),
                        int(self.value_fr_v.get()),int(self.value_b_v.get()),
                        int(self.value_w_v.get()),#vegetative
                        int(self.value_r_f.get()),int(self.value_hr_f.get()),
                        int(self.value_fr_f.get()),int(self.value_b_f.get()),
                        int(self.value_w_f.get()),#flowering
                        int(self.value_r_c.get()),int(self.value_hr_c.get()),
                        int(self.value_fr_c.get()),int(self.value_b_c.get()),
                        int(self.value_w_c.get()),#custom
                        int(self.start_time_h.get()),int(self.start_time_m.get()),
                        int(self.start_time_s.get()),#starttime
                        int(self.stop_time_h.get()),int(self.stop_time_m.get()),
                        int(self.stop_time_s.get())]#stoptime
    sname = asksaveasfilename(defaultextension=".pickle",filetypes=(("PICKLE files", "*.pickle"),
                                       ("All files", "*.*") ))
    self.save_button.config(relief = 'raised')
    if sname:
        self.myfile = open(sname,'wb')
        pickle.dump(self.settings,self.myfile)
        self.myfile.close()

def read_setting(self,event):
    fname = askopenfilename(filetypes=(("PIKLE files", "*.pickle"),
                                       ("All files", "*.*")))
    if fname:
        self.myfile = open(fname,'rb')
        self.settings = pickle.load(self.myfile)
        self.load_setting()
        self.myfile.close()

def load_setting(self):
    #germination
    self.value_r_g.set(self.settings[0])
    self.value_hr_g.set(self.settings[1])
    self.value_fr_g.set(self.settings[2])
    self.value_b_g.set(self.settings[3])
    self.value_w_g.set(self.settings[4])
    #seedling
    self.value_r_s.set(self.settings[5])
    self.value_hr_s.set(self.settings[6])
    self.value_fr_s.set(self.settings[7])
    self.value_b_s.set(self.settings[8])
    self.value_w_s.set(self.settings[9])
    #vegetative
    self.value_r_v.set(self.settings[10])
    self.value_hr_v.set(self.settings[11])
    self.value_fr_v.set(self.settings[12])
    self.value_b_v.set(self.settings[13])
    self.value_w_v.set(self.settings[14])
    #flowering
    self.value_r_f.set(self.settings[15])
    self.value_hr_f.set(self.settings[16])
    self.value_fr_f.set(self.settings[17])
    self.value_b_f.set(self.settings[18])
    self.value_w_f.set(self.settings[19])
    #custom
    self.value_r_c.set(self.settings[20])
    self.value_hr_c.set(self.settings[21])
    self.value_fr_c.set(self.settings[22])
    self.value_b_c.set(self.settings[23])
    self.value_w_c.set(self.settings[24])
    #starttime
    self.start_time_h.set(self.settings[25])
    self.start_time_m.set(self.settings[26])
    self.start_time_s.set(self.settings[27])
    #stoptime
    self.stop_time_h.set(self.settings[28])
    self.stop_time_m.set(self.settings[29])
    self.stop_time_s.set(self.settings[30])

def main():
    ex = LEDChooser()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: We don't know - only you know the code.

Comment: add some of your code so we can help.+1 @furas

Comment: Thanks for your reply! The code has been added..

Comment: BTW, what could be the potential reasons? The program works in PC but not in ResPi...

Answer (score 0):

Don't really know why but try to set RPIO on DMA channel different from zero

```
self.servo = PWM.Servo(10, 3000, 1)
```

it works for me.